# Linq Combine two statements into one big statement (optimization)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which is using a lot of LINQ to set and match some values in a list of `Tuple<string, int>`.

Right now i'm still stuck with two foreach loops nested into eachother and i think it'd be possible to combine them into one gigantic LINQ query. I'm wondering what would be the best way to do this with optimization as a big condition.

This is the function i'm talking about:

```
private async void AddLocalChangesFromPendingOperations()
{
    var pendingOperations = await this.operationsStorage.GetOperationsAsync();
    var list = pendingOperations.
        SelectMany(pendingOperation =>
                           pendingOperation.Settings, (pendingOperation, setting) =>
                           new { pendingOperation, setting })
        .Where(a => a.setting.Key == "selection")
        .Select(a => new Tuple<string, int>(
                                             a.pendingOperation.DefinitionId,
                                             Convert.ToInt32(a.setting.Value.ValueObject)))
        .ToList();

    foreach (var pendingChange in list)
    {
        var selection = await this.selectionsStorage.GetSelectionByIdAsync(pendingChange.Item2);
        foreach (var selectionsViewModel in this.SelectionsList.Where(a => a.Name == selection.Name))
        {
            if (pendingChange.Item1 == "selection-add-animals")
            {
                selectionsViewModel.IsActive = true;
            }
            else if (pendingChange.Item1 == "selection-remove-animals")
            {
                selectionsViewModel.IsActive = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If possible i'd like to optimize the last two foreaches while using linq. I've tried something but i'm stuck on setting values in the current list...

I was doing this:

```
this.SelectionsList = this
    .SelectionsList
    .Where(a => a.Name == selection.Name)
    .SingleOrDefault(
        a => pendingChange.Item1 == "selection-add-animals" ? a.IsActive = true : a.IsActive = false
    );
```

Comment: Can't you just change the method GetSelectionByIdAsync to accept a list of ids, so you get rid of the first foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, LINQ is for querying items (Language Integrated `Query`). You could however do a query and then do a foreach at the end:

```
private async void AddLocalChangesFromPendingOperations()
{
    var pendingOperations = await this.operationsStorage.GetOperationsAsync();

    (await Task.WhenAll(pendingOperations
        .SelectMany(pendingOperation =>
                           pendingOperation.Settings, (pendingOperation, setting) =>
                           new { pendingOperation, setting })
        .Where(a => a.setting.Key == "selection")
        .Select(a => Tuple.Create(a.pendingOperation.DefinitionId, Convert.ToInt32(a.setting.Value.ValueObject)))
        .Select(async pendingChange => Tuple.Create(await this.selectionsStorage.GetSelectionByIdAsync(pendingChange.Item2)), pendingChange))
        .SelectMany(tuple => this.SelectionsList.Where(a => a.Name == tuple.Item1.Name)
                                                .Select(selectionsViewModel => Tuple.Create(selectionsViewModel, tuple.Item2))
        .Select(tuple => Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2.Item1 == "selection-add-animals"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(tuple => tuple.Item1.IsActive = tuple.Item2);
}
```

Whether this is clearer than your original implementation is up for discussion (I don't think it is), but it would be one way of doing it.

NOTE: This was typed into the editor directly, there might be some minor syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
this.SelectionsList = this.SelectionsList
    .Where(a => a.Name == selection.Name)
    .Select(a => 
    {
        a.IsActive = a.Name == selection.Name ? true:false;
        return a;
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: You know this does nothing due to LINQ deferred execution.

Comment: Yes, sorry you should execute query with ToList().